# Cannot read property "match" (nestedSortable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, nested-sortable, tree-structure

I have a tree structure that I'm trying to sort with a [jQuery nestedSortable plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/zgs7f81t/25/).

Here you can see my code and a working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.sortable').nestedSortable({
   handle: 'div',
   items: 'li',
   toleranceElement: '> div',
            change: function(){
                console.log('moved!');
                console.log(this);
                console.log($(this));
                var arraied = $(this).nestedSortable('toArray', {startDepthCount: 0});          
                arraied = dump(arraied);
                console.log(arraied);
            }
  });

 });
    
    function dump(arr,level) {
      var dumped_text = "";
      if(!level) level = 0;
      //The padding given at the beginning of the line.
      var level_padding = "";
      for(var j=0;j<level+1;j++) level_padding += "    ";

      if(typeof(arr) == 'object') { //Array/Hashes/Objects
          for(var item in arr) {
              var value = arr[item];

              if(typeof(value) == 'object') { //If it is an array,
                  dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' ...\n";
                  dumped_text += dump(value,level+1);
              } else {
                  dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' => \"" + value + "\"\n";
              }
          }
      } else { //Strings/Chars/Numbers etc.
          dumped_text = "===>"+arr+"<===("+typeof(arr)+")";
      }
      return dumped_text;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js"></script>
<ol class="sortable">
 <li><div>List line 1</div></li>
 <li>
  <div>List line 2</div>
  <ol>
   <li><div>List line 3</div></li>
   <li><div>List line 4</div></li>
  </ol>
 </li>
 <li><div>List line 5</div></li>
</ol>
```

You can move nodes around the tree, so that's working fine. Unfortunately, I'm not able to get a response array so I can update my database values.

If you check the browser console while moving around those tiny little node things, you can see that I constantly get the error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined".

What could be the reason of this error and, equally important, how can I get an array after a tree adjustment?

Answer (score 2):

in jquery.mjs.nestedSortable v2.0), replace line 769 :

```
id = ($(item).attr(o.attribute || "id")).match(o.expression || (/(.+)[-=_](.+)/));
```

with:

```
id = ($(item).attr(o.attribute || "id") ||'').match(o.expression || (/(.+)[-=_](.+)/));
```